# Create Android app in Netbeans to Android Mobile

Tags: java, android, netbeans

How can I run my android application that I have created using Netbeans on an Android mobile?

I have read this "How to run J2ME application directly on the mobile from NetBeans?"

and the answer was:

> In Netbeans, right click your project and click on 'Build'. Now
>   navigate to the directory where your project is stored and go to the
>   folder called 'dist'. In that, you will find a JAR file with the name
>   of your project. Copy that to your cellphone and execute it.

Does this works for Android as well?

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient. Android application format is `APK`, not `JAR`, and you need more things set up to make valid app. Please follow any basic Android tutorial to gain elementary knowledge.